# I am trying to convert the "Return First recurring character in a string problem" from python to powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I have completed coding this same problem in python and was trying to generate a similar logic or atleast achieve a similar result in powershell.
Python Code-

```
def FRC(str):
    h = {}

    for ch in str:
        if ch in h:
            return ch
        else:
            h[ch] = 0
    return '\0'
print(FRC("abcdedcba"))
```

I have tried a few possible codes and was able to only enumerate the array of characters to count their occurrences. Thank you for any suggestions.

**Update1 - The code I have worked on is as follows:**

```
function get-duplicatechar {
   [CmdletBinding()]
   param (
     [string]$teststring
   )

   $hash = @()
   $teststring = $teststring.ToCharArray()

   foreach ($letter in $teststring)
   {
        if($letter -contains $hash){
        return $letter
        }else {
        $hash = $hash + $letter
        }
      return "\0"
    }
}

get-duplicatechar("saahsahh")
```

Comment: If you post some of the code you’ve tried so far we can help you understand where it’s going wrong...

Comment: I have just added the code  that I used. Please take a look at that. Thanks

Comment: [1] this `$hash = @()` is not a hashtable ... it's an array. ///// [2] your `-contains` test is looking to see if ONE letter contains a collection of letters. that doesn't make sense. [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working version using your code as base:

```
function get-duplicatechar {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
    [string]$teststring
    )
    $hash = @{}
    $CharArray = $teststring.ToCharArray()

    foreach ($letter in $CharArray) {
        if($letter -in $hash.Keys) {
            $letter
            break
        }
        else {
            $hash[$letter] = $null
        }
    }
}
```

One problem is that you are strongly typing $teststring to be a string, so when you add a character array later PowerShell just converts it into a string and thus $teststring remains a string (try `$teststring.GetType()` after `$teststring = $teststring.ToCharArray()` to see this for yourself).

One way to solve this is to do what I did and use a different variable for the character array. You could also solve it by changing the variable to a character array directly by replacing `[string]$teststring` with `[char[]]$teststring`, that way any strings input to the function will be automatically cast as a character array.

The next mistake is using `-contains` where you need `-in`. The letter doesn't contain the array, you're looking for the letter *in* the array, just like you did in Python.

You can drop the return keyword entirely, PowerShell does not need it. Any output in your function will be output from the function automatically.

You also call your collection variable "hash", but you made an array. I changed it to be an actual hashtable, just like in your Python code. I also changed the way we add to it to more closely reflect what you did in Python. There are many ways to do this, this is just one. Notice we'll need to add ".Keys" in our if-statement as well so we check for keys matching our letter.

I think that's it, ask if anything is unclear.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the (.Net) [`HashSet` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=net-5.0) for this, which [`Add` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.add?view=net-5.0#System_Collections_Generic_HashSet_1_Add__0_) (besides adding the value,) returns `true` if the element is added to the `HashSet<T>` object and `false` if the element is already present.

```
function get-duplicatechar {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
      [string]$str
    )

    $h = [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[char]]::new()

    foreach ($ch in $str.ToCharArray()) {
        if(!$h.add($ch)) { return $ch }
    }
}
```

Comment: A slightly shorter syntax for creating an empty `HashSet` is: `[System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[char]] $h = @()`. One can also initialize it with some values, like `[System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[char]] $h = 'a', 'c', 'd'`.